# Uppercase package name issue with enpkg

Tags: python, enthought

I'm trying to install the 'Qt' package into my [EPD Free Edition install](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php) using the enpkg tool. This is on Windows.

enpkg works OK for lowercase packages:

```
H:\>enpkg pandas
prefix: C:\Python27
No update necessary, 'pandas' is up-to-date.
pandas-0.10.1-1.egg was installed on: Mon Apr 08 15:07:14 2013
```

But it seems to handle uppercase package names incorrectly:

```
H:\>enpkg Qt
prefix: C:\Python27
No egg found for requirement 'qt'.

H:\>enpkg "Qt"
prefix: C:\Python27
No egg found for requirement 'qt'.
```

I know [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) is available as I can install it on Mac OS X, and I see it in the EPD package directory: http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try it with any other packages with uppercase letters, to confirm it is a case problem and not just a problem with that particular package?

Comment: Doh! Very good point, it looks like the EPD free distribution doesn't give me access to Qt, as this works:H:\>enpkg PIL
prefix: C:\Python27
No update necessary, 'pil' is up-to-date.
PIL-1.1.7-3.egg was installed on: Mon Apr 08 11:50:47 2013

Comment: Is it possible the package is actually called PyQt?  There is a Python package called PyQt, and it may be that that's just incorrectly listed as Qt in the list.

Comment: Related: [Change case of package name on PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17460747/320399) and [Is PyPI case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26503509/320399)

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, this is not an issue of case sensitivity.

What you use in Python is not Qt directly but the Python wrappers for Qt, which might be either PySide (available to free users) or PyQt4 (GPL license, available only to subscribers, not available on OSX-64). Enthought recommends using PySide unless you have unusual requirements for PyQt4 wrappers.

So what you should do on all platforms is `enpkg pyside`.

On Mac OS X and Linux, Qt is a separate package which enpkg automatically installs as a dependency of PySide.

On Windows, for now, Qt itself is bundled into PySide, so there is no separate package named Qt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EPD free distribution doesn't give access to Qt, as this works fine:

```
H:\>enpkg PIL
prefix: C:\Python27
No update necessary, 'pil' is up-to-date.
PIL-1.1.7-3.egg was installed on: Mon Apr 08 11:50:47 2013
```

I guess I will have to try installing it manually, or cough up for an Enthought license...