# Change case of package name on PyPI

Tags: python, package, pypi

I recently uploaded a package to PyPI under a name with mixed-case letters, QualysAPI.
In retrospect I think it'd be better to have the package name be all lowercase per [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). Is there a way I can change it?

Here's what happens when I try manually edit the package name on Pypi:

> Forbidden
>
> Package name conflicts with existing package 'QualysAPI'

Here's what happens when I try to edit the package name via `python setup.py sdist upload`:

> Upload failed (403): You are not allowed to edit 'qualysapi' package information

Answer (score 8):

Deleted package. Reupload package with all lowercase. Lost all history of package but doesn't matter since Github has revisions online.