# Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use `pyinstaller` in cmd but I receive error:

```
C:\Users\username>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\username>
```

When I use this command in the **Scripts** folder in python , it works:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pyinstaller
usage: pyinstaller [-h] [-v] [-D] [-F] [--specpath DIR] [-n NAME]
                   [--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]
                   [--add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [-p DIR]
                   [--hidden-import MODULENAME]
                   [--additional-hooks-dir HOOKSPATH]
                   [--runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS] [--exclude-module EXCLUDES]
                   [--key KEY] [-d] [-s] [--noupx] [-c] [-w]
                   [-i <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns>]
                   [--version-file FILE] [-m <FILE or XML>] [-r RESOURCE]
                   [--uac-admin] [--uac-uiaccess] [--win-private-assemblies]
                   [--win-no-prefer-redirects]
                   [--osx-bundle-identifier BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER]
                   [--distpath DIR] [--workpath WORKPATH] [-y]
                   [--upx-dir UPX_DIR] [-a] [--clean] [--log-level LEVEL]
                   [--upx UPX]
                   scriptname [scriptname ...]
pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to modify your User PATH environment variable to include `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`.

For how to add/modify your PATH environment variables, see [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: you can shorten the path like so - `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`

Comment: but the folder was in `AppData/roaming` folder for me instead of `Appdata/local`. So I used - `%AppData%\Python\Python311\Scripts`

Answer (score 52):

I had to run `python -m PyInstaller script.py` for it to work.

Even though the Python script directory is configured correctly in the environment variable PATH, you can observe that there is no script named PyInstaller. When you `pip install`, the module goes into `[python directory]/lib/site-packages`.

To run a Python module, follow the pattern `python -m [script name] [args]`.

Python version: 3.10.0

Comment: Ahhhhh, case sensitive...

Answer (score 10):

First, you need to know where is the pyinstaller locates.
In my case, I ran

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

Before it's being uninstalled, it will ask you to confirm if you want to remove the following file...

```
c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\scripts\pyinstaller.exe
```

Great! Now by doing this, you know your path to pyinstaller. Simple type 'No' and exit the uninstallation as our purpose is just to get the path.
Now just add this path to the PATH variable.

```
c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\scripts\
```

For how to change your PATH variable. Check [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 9):

For Python 3.7, you will have to add the Scripts folder from AppData/Roaming (%appdata%) to the PATH variable.

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

Answer (score 9):

Copy 'pyinstaller.exe' to the folder you have the .py file you want to convert. When you are done, just delete 'pyinstaller.exe'. Good luck.

Comment: moving an executable around is really cumbersome if you need it often, setting the path variable is much more elegant

Answer (score 7):

If you are using python 3.10 or higher, chance are that the pyinstaller is not added to your Path variables. To avoid all of that setup, you can simply run

```
python -m PyInstaller [path to your file] [args]
```

For example I ran

```
python -m PyInstaller ./frontend.py --onefile
```

Answer (score 6):

**This solution work for Python 3.9**

First of all find the **pyinstaller.exe** location. To do this you could try this trick: (do not press 'y' just look at the above copy the path what you are looking for)

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

Before typing anything, it will show you the path where the pyinstaller.exe is. After that copy the location and run this command on terminal: *(it is an example)*

```
python C:\Users\[YOUR_USER_NAME]\AppData\...Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile [your_script_name.py]
```

Answer (score 3):

Goto - "C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\Scripts" path and copy "pyinstaller.exe"
and paste it in the directory where you want to use pyinstaller, it worked for me

Comment: anaconda3 is not found

Answer (score 2):

I found How we should fix this error :

```
C:\Users\username>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

We should enter this code in cmd pip install pyinstaller
if it is doesn't work again you should go `C:/user/pc name/Appdata` (Appdata folder is hide)/python
now you should copy script folder and `C:/program files/python39`
and copy site package to `C:/program files/python39/lib`

then if you type pyinstaller in cmd you see it work

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, for me changing the capitalization resolved the issue.
I typed `python -m [scriptname] [args]`. In `[scriptname]` I typed `PyInstaller` instead of `pyinstaller` and it actually worked. I tried both ways multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot do anything or you have less time, you can make the virtual environment and install pyinstaller there, then generate executable file

Answer (score 1):

Copy youe script folder's path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts` and paste it in:
`environment varibales> system varibales> path` and save it.
Then restart your PC and try running pyinsatller from anywhere it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue:

- Locate your Python folder and go to `Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages`
- From there delete the Pyinstaller module and Pyinstaller dis.info folder
- Reinstall Pyinstaller using `pip install pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open command `cmd` from this path: ctrl+r, write "cmd" in box
2. Uninstall pyinstaller: `pip uninstall pyinstaller`
3. Install it again: `pip install pyinstaller`
4. Use the pyinstaller by writing `pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

Enter in Administrative Console: pip install pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check the configuration, ports, and active process.

After checking these processes, you can check the local folder.

You will find the pyinstaller inside this folder; there will be a `pyinstaller.exe` file.

Then set the path

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`,

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`.

After that, you can run the command `pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py`

Answer (score 0):

If installing pyinstaller and creating the 'path' variables still does not work, u can use this workaround:

Locate **pyinstaller.exe** from possible python directory like
C:\Users\ "UserName" **\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts**

Copy it to the dir that you have the .py file you want to compile as .exe

Use following command in terminal:
**.\pyinstaller** --onefile YOUR_FILE_NAME.py

Answer (score 0):

For me and on python version 3.9.12 the below command worked. The 'P' and 'I' in PyInstaller is capital. Also, I reinstalled the python package. Please see below the steps.

1. `python -m pip uninstall pyinstaller` -- for uninstalling the python package
2. `python -m pip install pyinstaller` -- for installing the python package
3. `python -m PyInstaller` -- and followed by rest of the attributes.

Comment: The capitals do not matter in the first two commands, since [PyPi is case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503509/is-pypi-case-sensitive). For the last command it does matter indeed, but there's nothing new to your post. Calling PyInstaller this way is already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780822/10669875). Reinstalling the package is also mentioned a few times already. If you post an answer to an old question with 18 answers already, please make sure your answer adds something new, and explain what's new in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have `pip` in the PATH of your `cmd`, then you can run these commands in `cmd` for **windows**.

1. `python -m pip install pyinstaller` - for installing pyinstaller.
2. `python -m pip uninstall pyinstaller` - for uninstalling pyinstaller.