# 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

So I made an app with Python and I want to make it an executable with PyInstaller, but the Command Prompt doesn't recognize the command.

[image: The command]

I've been searching the whole internet but nothing helps. I successfully uninstalled and installed Pyinstaller again but it still doesn't work.

[image: This shows it's installed]

I thought I would make my first StackOverflow post. (I'm pretty new to programming and I'm 15)

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do any of these answers help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)?

Answer (score 1):

you have to modify your PATH environment to include this:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>

if you don't know how to do it look [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), good luck....