# Find PyInstaller path?

Tags: python, windows, path, pyinstaller

I have the same error as in this question, [Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

I add `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>`to system path as it says, but then I check and there is no `Python` folder under `Programs`.

How do I find where pyinstaller is located?

Answer (score 0):

This is where mine ended up:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

However that is with the Python installer directly from https://python.org. I think the installer from the Windows store puts things in different places. I think it is better to install from Python.org itself than the Windows store version for this reason.

In any case you can also find your "pyinstaller" by using Explorer and searching in %AppData%\Local for it.