# 'pyinstaller' is not recognized by cmd

Tags: python, cmd

In the following image, it is showing 'pyinstaller' is already installed:
[image: 1]

But as shown in image 2 it is not recognizing it!
[image: 2]

I tried to modify your PATH environment but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: [Please post textual items not as images but as text!!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374700)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Path environment variable, try to add `<Python path>` as well as `<Python path>/Scripts` paths as given below:

[image]