# Pyinstaller installed succesfully but not working

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

When I try to write pyinstaller 'filename' it gives me an error

```
pyinstaller 'filename'                                                                  
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                     
operable program or batch file.
```

Whatever I try

```
python -m pyinstaller 'filename'
`No module named pyinstaller`
```

Please tell solution for it (also, the pyinstaller is successfully installed)

Comment: repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your PATH environment to include

> `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>`

If You want to know how to set or change the PATH system variable, you can visit this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html).