# Kivy-Buildozer Android Packaging not working ('buildozer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)

Tags: python, kivy, packaging, buildozer

I did not find any solutions for this on the internet.

I am trying to create the Android apk file from my Kivy-Python file on Windows 10.

I followed the standard documentation (e.g. [this one](https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/) or [this one](https://readthedocs.org/projects/buildozer/downloads/pdf/latest/)).

I installed buildozer using the Pycharm IDE environment.

I open the command box from the path adress bar of the folder with my main python file.

But whenever I type 'buildozer init' in the command line, the terminal gives me this error message:

```
"'buildozer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

What can I do to fix this?

I found no single solution or reference for this. All questions asked are for Ubuntu systems, or for different kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some more research I found out that the problem is unrelated to Buildozer.

It's solvable in the same manner as [pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command) with this problem!