# Python into .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to convert my python file to a `.exe` file using `pyinstaller`. I have installed pyinstaller using `pip install pyinstaller`, but when I try use `pyinstaller` I get:

```
C:\Users\Varnith\Desktop\program>pyinstaller --onefile main.py
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: is it in the path? did you use a fully qualified path for pyinstaller and it still does not work?

Comment: This question has already been asked, lots of times: "Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command" https://stackoverflow.com/q/45951964/13990016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pyinstaller hasn't been added to path. Make sure you installed it properly. If on Windows, try:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

or

```
py -m pip install pyinstaller
```

Otherwise, `pip3` & `python3`