# Convert .py to .exe with cmd

Tags: python, exe

I was trying to convert my `main.py` to a exe file

I followed a tutorial on youtube i did it like it said

first open cmd in the folder
[image]

then type in `pip install pyinstaller`
[image]
then type in like this `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`
but it does'nt convert it shows this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command) take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Eyal's solution is correct, there is an easier option. Just run this:

```
py -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py
```

It could also be `python -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py` depending on your system configuration.

Comment: thank you the 2nd one worked

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused because `pyinstaller` is not in the PATH environment variable.

First, find the full path of pyinstaller.exe - it should be in the Scripts directory of your Python installation (probably `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\[Python_VER]\Scripts`). Copy the full path.

Then open a command prompt (as Administrator) and run the command:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;PYINSTALLER_PATH"
```

where PYINSTALLER_PATH is the full path of pyinstaller you have copied.

Then re-launch command prompt and run the command again.