# Unable to use pyinstaller in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I need to create an executable file from multiple python files and I chose to go with pyinstaller. I installed it with `pip install pyinstaller`. But when I executed the command of `pyinstaller --onefile Main.py`, I got the following error:

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I checked [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command) for the solution to this problem and tried out the following options but none of them could solve the issue:

1. Added python scripts folder to env path.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled pyinstaller
3. Copied pyinstaller.exe and pyinstaller-script.py to project directory.

The third option did give some progress but I still couldn't get it to work. I copied the pyinstaller.exe and pyinstaller-script.py to the location of my python files location. Running the pyinstaller command again gave me the following error:

```
Unable to create process using 'D:\Projects\FSS\python.exe "D:\Projects\FSS\FSS Mini PC Application\pyinstaller-script.py" --onefile -w Main.py'
```

My user environment variables are as follows:

[image]

My system environment variables are as follows:
[image]

I am stuck on this problem and would appreciate some help.

Comment: try creating a virtual enviornment then install pyinstaller and try again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I used

```
py -m pip install pyinstaller
```

and it worked
.