# PyInstaller is installed in a weird way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm beginner in Python. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but i cannot make pyinstaller work on python 3.12
[image]

When i run pip list package version it is there :

[image]

however when i enter C:/Python312/Scripts there are only pip.exe
there's no pyinstaller.exe

Python is added to PATH but
From what I noticed pyinstaller is in C:/Python312/Lib/site-packages and I added this folder to PATH as well just to be sure but it's still not working.

What could be possibly wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked this thread out? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Comment: @MouSamDahal Yep, i cannot even find pyinstaller.exe anywhere.... :/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem was solved by uninstalling it.
And then from separated admin console installing it again.
Before i was installing it from vscode console and i presume this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pyinstaller is not added to the PATH automatically, like you said reinstalling will help with that.

Just

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install pyinstaller
```

If it not work, may be pip has no permissions to edit PATH