# python ImportError: cannot import name 'Faker' from 'faker'

Tags: python, django, django-models, faker, python-datamodel

hello so I've been writing this script to pre-populate my Django database but when I stopped writing it I got a weird error:
My Script:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

## FAKE POPULATION SCRIPT:

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

# Creating a fake generator:
fakegen = Faker
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N = 5):

    for entry in range(N):

        # GET THE TOPIC FOR THE ENTRY:
        top = add_topic()

        # Create the fake data for that entry:
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

    # Create the new webpage entry:
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

    # Create a fake access record for that webpage
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating Script!")
    populate(20)
    print("Populating Complete!")
```

The error I get:

```
python populate_first_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from faker import Faker
  File "E:\Python\Projects\Python And Django FullStack\Django\first_project\faker.py", line 1, in <module>
    from faker import Faker
ImportError: cannot import name 'Faker' from 'faker'
```

I've never seen the error like this I am using this script under the influence of a virtual environment which I already installed all the packages I already checked a few things like uninstalling and installing the 'faker' library again but it didn't work and I still get the error.

Answer (score 26):

You've got a file in your project called "faker.py" which is hiding the library you installed. Rename that file.

Comment: thanks to keeping me sane for a short time!

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and it worked for me.

I used the following commands to uninstall the Faker and faker(just to be sure) that I previously installed using pip and pip3 from my venv

```
pip uninstall Faker

pip uninstall faker

pip3 uninstall Faker

pip3 uninstall faker
```

and then I used the following command to re-install the Faker in my venv using conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge faker
```

Comment: `pip` is case insensitive based on this [answer (and PEP 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585483/14531062)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions and your issue will be fixed:-

1) make sure you installed Faker library in your virtual env use the following command for that :-

```
pip install Faker
```

it'll install the latest version of faker on you virtual env.

2) now make sure you import it like this in your project :-

```
from faker import Faker
```

and BINGO your issue is fixed happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Never create a python file with name "faker.py" to store faker module code because faker name is already available in the python installed scripts. For more details you can check in the following location "C:\Python 3.7\Scripts". You can give any name to the file other than faker ex: one.py or two.py to store faker module related code.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe doing this in VS-Code, So select your particular environment in left_bottom of vs code ,select the python environment you created for django project.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.