# Failed to run IPython Notebook: bash: IPython: command not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've installed Ipython 6.0.0 successfully using Pip3:

```
pip3 install IPython
```

but when tried to run the command

```
Ipython
```

I got this error:

```
 bash: IPython: command not found
```

This is the `pip list` result:

- ipykernel (5.1.3)
- ipython (6.0.0)
- ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
- ..
- ..
- notebook (6.0.2)

and this is the result of `pip3 show IPython`

```
 Name: ipython
 Version: 6.0.0
 Summary: IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
 Home-page: https://ipython.org
 Author: The IPython Development Team
 Author-email: ipython-dev@python.org
 License: BSD
 Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
 Requires: setuptools, traitlets, jedi, pexpect, pygments, pickleshare, simplegeneric, prompt-toolkit, decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of case sensitivity...

The correct typography is IPython.

pip *is not* case sensitive, see [Is PyPI case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503509/is-pypi-case-sensitive)
IPython is installed as ipython (lowercase), as shown in your `pip3 show IPython`

bash *is* case sensitive...

So, just enter `ipython`.

As you have specified `pip3`, I would also recommend to invoke `ipython3` to avoid python2/3 confusions.