# Installing PIL on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I need to install PIL but `pip install pillow` doesn't work. I get the error below. I had PIL but since it didnt work, I uninstalled and now I can't install it.

```
Searching for Pillow
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/Pillow/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/Pillow/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'Pillow' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for Pillow
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('Pillow')
```

Comment: Did you run `pip install pillow` or `pip install Pillow`?

Comment: Have you made sure to do `source activate <environment name>` before running pip install? Could you also add statements of pip install or any other statements that might be helpful

Comment: Go to https://pypi.org/simple/pillow/ in browser, download package you need install it like pip install path/to/file .

Comment: @mkrieger1 doesn't matter. Pip install is case insensitive. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503509/is-pypi-case-sensitive