# Pip case sensitivity

Tags: python, module, pip, pypi

This is probably a very stupid question, but I must ask it. Is pip case sensitive? When I execute `pip install flask` is it the same as `pip install Flask`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26503509/1358308 seems more authoritative

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `pip` is case sensitive. If you have **a file** `Flask.whl` on your **case sensitive filesystem** (Unix ones) you can install it with `pip install Flask.whl` but cannot install it with `pip install flask.whl`: `pip` replies with *ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flask.whl'*

Packages at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) and similar repositories are case-insensitive. User names and repository names at GitHub are also case-insensitive so you can do

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pallets/flask/
```

or

```
pip install git+https://GitHub.com/Pallets/Flask/
```

or any case variation. But other VCS hosts could be case-sensitive.

Comment: @paavoto This is about PyPI and compatible indices. They're case-insensitive. But `pip` is case-sensitive. Aren't examples in my answer enough?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I must've misread it or something. Your answer was completely fine

Answer (score -2):

No, pip is not case sensitive. All comparisons of distribution names must be case insensitive, and must consider hyphens and underscores to be equivalent.