# Is conda case sensitive?

Tags: python, conda

This question is related to [Is PyPI case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503509/is-pypi-case-sensitive)

Given that `pip` is case insensitive, is `conda` also case insensitive for package names?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're specifically asking about *package names*, right? I ask cause when I googled "conda case sensitive", the [first result was about *environment* names](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8813).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conda doesn't even allow uppercase in package names in the first place.

> Conda package names are normalized and they may contain only lowercase alpha characters, numeric digits, underscores, hyphens, or dots.

from [the conda-build docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/concepts/package-naming-conv.html)

Comment: And the Conda CLI implicitly converts specifications to all lower, e.g., `conda create -n foo -d pYtHoN=3.10 NuMpY` works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.
In my Knowledge conda is case sensitive just like pip.

Comment: Case sensitivity actually isn't even a factor because Conda only allows lowercase in package names. See [my answer](/a/72833637/4518341).

Comment: Well, both ways......

Comment: Oh wait, I thought you wrote "case **in**sensitive". Conda is not case-sensitive (since it only allows one case), neither is pip (since all comparisons are case-insensitive).

Comment: Definitely case *in*sensitive: `conda create -n foo -d pYtHoN=3.10 NuMpY` installs `python=3.10` and `numpy`.